# How to set identity to managed for Azure Data Factory using Python SDK?

Tags: python, azure-sdk-python

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity) I see that there's support for the .NET sdk in generating an Azure Data Factory with managed identity.  However, I can't find anything out there for the Python SDK.  Here are a few of my attempts:

```
factoryID = new FactoryIdentity()
    df_obj = {
        'location': self.location,
        'identity': factoryID
        }

    df_resource = Factory(df_obj)
```

Which returns syntax error:

```
 factoryID = new FactoryIdentity()
                               ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And I also tried:

```
        df_resource = Factory(location=self.location, Identity = new FactoryIdentity())
```

Which returned the same thing:

```
df_resource = Factory(location=self.location, Identity = new FactoryIdentity())
                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've searched for hours in the docs and on S.O.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

df_resource = Factory(location=self.location, **identity=FactoryIdentity()**)

Can't find anything about this online (for Python) so I'm sharing here.

Works!